# Does a class help creating a pipeline in Java 17? I would like to refine a raw content to a fine object in multiple steps

Tags: java, pipeline

I have a process that start reading a raw document, then remove its unusable parts, then extract its chapters, do some detections, extract specific content, etc.

1. In my mind, the basic way to implement such pipeline is to use the **streams**:
   Dedicated functions going from `A` to `D` objects, representing the refinement steps achieved:
   `Stream<A>` → `Stream<B>` → `Stream<C>` → `Stream<D>`, and at the end, returning `D`.
2. A way looking cleaner to me, is to use **functions**:
   `Supplier<A>` or `A` → `Function<A,B>` → `Function<B,C>` → `Function<C,D>`, and returning `D`.

But does *Java* in its latest versions offers a more convenient structural, generic class, to help creating pipelines?
Seeing them as threads, for example, allowing to cancel one pipeline in one of its failing step... Or whatever useful help it offers.

Reading over the Internet and S.O., I've found that once, around the years 2010, a pipeline pattern appeared, but I saw it described in text and not code.

Comment: The way, how you get from a `Stream<A>` to a `Stream<B>` *is* by using a `Function<A,B>`, passing it to the [`map` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and when you are at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) note that the word “pipeline” appears about a thirty times in it, because the Stream API *is* a “convenient … generic class, to help creating pipelines” (not sure what “structural” means in this context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stream from `java.util.funtion.Function` and chain them with `andThen` method

```java
// declaring all pipelines
Supplier<String> startPipeline = () -> "string-input";
UnaryOperator<String> pipeline0 = s ->  s+= "-0";
UnaryOperator<String> pipeline1 = s ->  s+= "-1";
UnaryOperator<String> pipeline2 = s ->  s+= "-2";
UnaryOperator<String> pipeline3 = s ->  s+= "-3";
UnaryOperator<String> pipeline4 = s ->  s+= "-4";

// chain pipelines
String outputPipeline = pipeline0
                .andThen(pipeline1)
                .andThen(pipeline2)
                .andThen(pipeline3)
                .andThen(pipeline4)
                .apply(startPipeline.get()); // call them with inital value
              
// print result          
System.out.println(outputPipeline); // it will print string-input-0-1-2-3-4
```

> `java.util.funtion.UnaryOperator<String>` is same as `java.util.funtion.Function<String,String>`

Comment: Yes it's the idea.

Comment: Don’t use the `+=` operator in this misleading way. In your code, the `+=` operator modifiers the parameter variable which has no persisting effect. In other words, `s ->  s+= "-0"` has the same effect as `s -> s + "-0"` but the latter makes it obvious what it does.